# How to make canvas and containing image responsive in fabric js

Tags: html, fabricjs

I am using fabric js and canvas to add image from url I want to make canvas and containing image responsive as per resolution.How can we do it?
my code is:-

```
<canvas id="panel" width="700" height="350"></canvas>   

<script>
 (function() {
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('panel');
        var rect;
        fabric.Image.fromURL('abc.jpg', function (img) {
                canvas.add(img.set({
                    width: canvas.width,
                    height:canvas.height,
                    originX :'left',
                    originY :'top',
                    selectable: false,

                }));
            });


    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there are no inbuilt functions to achieve this.

But canvas can be made responsive by using native javascript and playing with the screen width and screen height, setting them as canvas width and height.

And same maths you have to apply for all the items drawn in the canvas. (take the ratio of your canvas width or height to screen width or height and use this ratio to resize all the elements on change of view-ports).

Hope it will help you.